# How do I keep the cursor in the middle of the console?

Tags: command-line, bash

As we know when the command line hits the bottom of the terminal, the input cursor stays at the bottom of the terminal, which makes it a little uncomfortable to see. So I want to make the line with input cursor stay in the middle of the screen. Is there any way to set this up?

For example, I want the command line with the cursor to always stay in the red frame:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be Ubuntu-on-Windows.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju - Looks like SSH to me.

Comment: @AndroidDev Ah, I see the PuTTY icon.

Comment: Why don't you just make your terminal window smaller?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to keep it ever in the middle, since text output also goes there.

Rather, we can bring it back at the top (but not stay there):

```
clear
```

Comment: tnx is there any customize function write in the bashrc can make it?

Comment: No, but no matter where the cursor is, you can type and it'll get to the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You need tmux.

```
sudo apt install tmux
```

Run the terminal application - oh no! cursor at the bottom :(

[image]

Run tmx

```
tmux
```

Create a vertical split by doing the following:

- Press Ctrl-b
- Release keys
- Press shift-2 (or wherever your " is)

You will see this:

[image]

To move between upper and lower terminals:

- Press Ctrl-b and release
- Press up or down cursor key

You can now sit in the top terminal and it'll always scroll at the middle.